# Question on creating a ROS Workspace during installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am installing ROS1 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed the steps up to Section 3. Create a ROS Workspace of the installation tutorial.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Install_ROS

I have executed:

$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src

$ cd ~/catkin_ws/

$ catkin_make

If I stay with Python 2.7, do I still need to execute the following two commands after catkin_make?

$ source devel/setup.bash

$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348587/question-on-creating-a-ros-workspace-during-installation/) by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-06**:
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

It is not needed, however, always when you're going to use a workspace you **must** source the **setup.bash**

"This command tells which packages are inside the workspace."

And it is not directly connected with your Python Version.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [new_to_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/52069/new_to_ros/) on 2020-04-06**:
Thank you.